# Retain on NSManagedObject crashes

Tags: objective-c

I'm experiencing a weird problem when trying to use an NSManagedObject subclass. I've got code that looks something like this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
MyController *myController = [[MyController alloc] init];
myController.managedObject = managedObject;
```

Pretty simple right? But for some reason it crashes in the synthesized function for setting "managedObject". I tried replacing the function with something like this:

```
- (void) SetManagedObject:(NSManagedObjectSubClass*) obj
{
   if ( managedObject )
      [managedObject release];

   managedObject = obj;
-->   [managedObject retain];
}
```

And that crashes on the retain call... I'm stumped and don't know where to start debugging this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- If you provide a custom setter, your property is not a synthesized property (remove `SetManagedObject:` and use the `@synthesized` directive instead)
- Your custom setter is releasing the object before it retains it. So `managedObject` might have been freed when you send the retain message (That's the crasher)
- `SetManagedObject:` has the wrong case. Use s`etManagedObject:` if you decide to provide a custom setter.
- Don't use NS as prefix for your custom subclasses (NS is used by Apple).

I'd use a synthesized property. Remove your setter code, declare `@property(retain) XYManagedObjectSubClass` managedObject; in your .h file and use `@synthesize` in the implementation.

Comment: I think you need to read the question more carefully. If you re-read the question, you'll see that I was using the synthesized function before but that was crashing so I intentionally created my own function ( to replace the synthesized one) to see where it was crashing. Turns out it crashes on the retain. And if you look at my function I don't release the object I release the PREVIOUS object. There's a big difference.

Comment: You are right. I misread the question - Sorry. Another idea would be that you are passing in an over-released object obj. Did you already  try to run your code with the "Zombies" Instrument?

Comment: It seems like my "obj" obj didn't have the right number of retain and release. Probably because I accessed it directly at one point instead of using self.obj. Anyway fixed now thanks for your answer.